# xmpp in IntentService only works when debugging

Tags: android, xmpp, google-cloud-messaging, intentservice

When implementing xmpp over the Cloud Connection Server of Google i receive messages that will start an `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`.

**Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.tag.xmppandroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.tag.xmppandroid.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
            <category android:name="com.tag.xmppandroid"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService"></service>
```

**WakefulBroadcastReceiver**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

Now this `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` will start an Intent service called `GcmIntentService.class`. The purpose of this intentService is receiving the message and directly send a message back as xmpp to the server that send the message. Actually this works, i send the message back with `gcm.send(...)` and the server receives the messages. **But only when im debugging**.

The server won't receive the message when the application is not in debugging mode. When the application is in debug mode it will send the message to the xmpp server. It looks like the thread shuts down to early and the message could not be send back to the server. But when im debugging i prevent the service from sleeping and it has time to send the message or anything. Does anyone know why this happens?

**Code of my Intentservice:**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    final GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);


    String message_id = null;
    String time_to_live = null;
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
    {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString(), null);
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            // Get values from intent send over xmpp
            message_id = ((intent.getExtras() == null) ? "Empty Bundle" : intent.getExtras().getString("message_id"));
            String message = ((intent.getExtras() == null) ? "Empty Bundle" : intent.getExtras().getString("message"));
            time_to_live = ((intent.getExtras() == null) ? "Empty Bundle" : intent.getExtras().getString("time_to_live"));


            Bundle data = new Bundle();
            data.putString("hello", "world");
            data.putString("delivered", "true");

            try {
                gcm.send(Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID + "@gcm.googleapis.com", message_id, Constants.GCM_TIME_TO_LIVE, data);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Send data to the view
            sendToView(message_id, message, time_to_live);

            // Show notification
            sendNotification("Received: " + message, extras);

            // Show toast on main thread
            Handler mHandler = new Handler(getMainLooper());
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Constants.GCM_SENDER_ID, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    } else {
        sendToView("empty_bundle", null, null);
    }

    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
```

I hope someone can explain me why this happens, or what i do wrong since i really want to understand why this happens.

Comment: Did you got a solution for this, I am also facing the same problem